# Why does cat pdf_file changes the character set of terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I was reading through Introduction to Linux by Machtelt Garrels and read about the `cat` command.

I tried to open a pdf file using `cat`. After opening the file the whole character set of the terminal changed, what is the reason behind this?

Below is the before/after screenshots

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Unless I restart the terminal, the english characters won't return. Is there a way to get back the original characters without restarting the terminal?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-using-cat-on-binary-files-messed-up-the-terminal-and-how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entering `reset` should fix it again.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is not a normal text file. You shouldn't `cat` it anyways. There are programs for reading a PDF.

Comment: Yes, PDF is a binary format.  If you `cat` any binary file, there is a potential that you will have this issue.  You can run `reset` in your terminal to fix this issue, or close and re-open a new terminal.